# Wordpress backend script to show page URL's

Tags: php, jquery, database, wordpress, custom-fields

Is there a plugin or another way...
Basically in the backend of wordpress I want the user to be able to select a file or page from a drop down list and then it displays the URL so they can copy and paste it into the content filed for easy linking?

**Example:**

```
they select a file
    document.pdf
and in a box below it displays the URL
    /wp-content/uploads/2013/10/document.pdf
```

so then they can copy and paste that URL into their content?
Been looking for a while to figure this out but no luck as of yet!

I'm also using Advanced Custom Fields if this can help?

Basically this is what I have so far.. I have two fields in the back end, a page_link select field & a text field. The page_link lists all linkable objects (pages, attachments, images..etc) and in the functions.php file I have this code..

```
function add_jquery_data() { 
global $parent_file;?>
<script>  
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
        jQuery("#acf-field-select_content").change(function() {
            var str = "";
            jQuery("option:selected", this).each(function() {
                str += jQuery(this).val();
            });
            jQuery("#acf-field-show_content_url").val(str);
        })
        .trigger("change");
    });
</script>
<?php }
add_filter('admin_head', 'add_jquery_data');
```

What this is doing is grabbing the value of the option in the select field and placing it in the text field.. but wordpress only puts the object ID in the value! So all im getting is a number not a full URL.. Any ideas?

http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/1472/5zy2.png
Here's a screenshot for a better understanding

Comment: With your current setup you'll need to do an `ajax` call using [wp_get_attachment_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) server side

Comment: And how would one go about doing this>?

Comment: Or you change the value of the options fields with the desired url or as qwillie said you can do it with an ajax call.